# Why does Empathy say my connection is untrusted?

Tags: empathy, certificates, signature

Today when I opened Empathy on Ubuntu 10.10 I got this unusual error box. I have never got this warning about an untrusted connection before.

What should I do? Is it a security risk if I continue without a second guess?

[image: screenshot of the dialog box]

Comment: I doubt it's a problem. Does everything work as expected if you click Continue? You have the latest Empathy, and you're using the standard Facebook Chat account setting? (That is, not some kind of Jabber workaround?) ... I just tried it myself and it works flawlessly still.

Comment: I haven't pressed continue yet and closed Empathy right after this warning, Everything else works just great and I have a fully updated ubuntu system. And yes I am using the standard facebook chat account setting nothing else.

Comment: I would have guessed they let their certificate expire, too, except that if you look at the image, it says the certificate was issued on 2011-2-9 and expires on 2014-2-13, which is still a few years off.

I'm getting this error, too, every time I start up Empathy, even if I click on the "Remember this choice for future connections" flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug open on Launchpad relating to the DigiCert certificates not being installed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates/+bug/742889

If you're seeing this issue, please mark the bug as affecting you; it may help expedite a fix.

Answer (score 4):

They let their SSL certificate lapse, while funny, not really a big deal with facebook. If it were say your bank you should back off. This was quite in the news but happened. No worries though. As you can see here it is not the first time they let it happen http://www.liewcf.com/facebook-ssl-certificate-6695/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that it is expired. The problem is that it is self-signed and Empathy does not recognize the issuer as a Certificate Authority.

My problem is that I check the box "Remember this choice for future connections" and click Continue, but I am still prompted every time I log in.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://lamaquinadiferencial.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/error-al-conectar-al-chat-de-facebook-this-connection-is-untrusted/).

The solution was to export DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 from firefox preferences

**Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Encryption > View Certificates > Authorities**

Save as `DigiCertHighAssuranceCA-3.crt`

Copy to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla` (file owner should be root)

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and check all certificates including DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 which were previously unchecked.

Comment: Firefox didn't has that certificate here. But you can it also download from https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm

Comment: this doesn't work for me. the certificate is installed but it still complains.